# While loop with jQuery AJAX pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

Ok, here's my problem. I am working with an API that uses pagination. I keep looping until the response back is a blank array. However, this does not work and the code just hangs. Every loop, I increment the page variable to get the next page.

```
// Function to get a list of 50 assignments.
function getAssignments(token, instuctureSubdomain, course, page, callback) {
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://" + instuctureSubdomain + ".instructure.com/api/v1/users/self/courses/" + course + "/assignments?per_page=50&page=" + page,
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      callback(response);
    });
};

var loop = true;
var page = 1;
while (loop) {
    getAssignments(token, instuctureSubdomain, item.id, page, function (response) {
        if (response.length == 0) {
// End the loop because the response returned a blank array.
            loop = false;
        } else {
            response.forEach(function (item) {
// Add the assignment to an array...
            });
            page++
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using console.log to see what results you're getting?  I would recommend starting there.

Comment: if the pagination show 10 at a time lets say and you have 48 results in total wont the final respose length be 8 and not 0?

Comment: @Harry True, but the loop should run again and then the API would return a blank array stopping the loop.

Comment: Does it change things if you write `if (response.length < number of page items) { loop = false; }` instead?

Comment: @Harry Nope, another thing is I tried adding a console.log at the beginning of the loop and I am getting no response at all.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking about how this will work - you have a `while` loop that is calling `getAssignments`, and the `getAssignments` is doing an AJAX transaction.  It seems that some return must be made from `getAssignments` and I could see this just repeating the while loop quite rapidly, queueing up many requests?  I would check the dev tools "Network" transactions and see what is happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would write it.  It won't lag/freeze your webpage with tons of requests and calls it, practically, synchronously.

```
<script>

function loop (i) {
    $.get("http://example.com/api/" + i + ".php", function (data) {
        array = process(data);
        if (array.length > 0) {
            loop(i + 1);
        }
    });
}

loop(1);

</script>
```